# O(n) function circumstance

Tags: time, big-o, time-complexity

So the question:

under what circumstances is a function f(n) said to be O(g(n))?

My Answer:

When f(n) contains a nested for loop iterating of n?

Is this at all on the right track?

Comment: What happens when the loop body itself takes O(n) time?

Comment: Iterating of n which completes in constant time? Or am I even further down the wrong path now?

Comment: That's quite close. It's not very precise, though. If you look up the definition of big-O in a textbook and plug in *n*, you'll get the exact conditions for a function growing as O(n).